Flutter MacOS fails build - cant find new class
I am trying to base my app on this statusbar app template
https://github.com/sky1095/flutter_macos_statusbar
Here, they add the StatusBarController.swift into flutterapp/macos and the project builds fine on my machine. I copied that file into my project, same location and adjusted the AppDelegate.swift accordingly.
However, the build fails with
flutter run -d macos
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
/Users/me/Documents/flutter/macos/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:10:28: error: cannot find type 'StatusBarController' in scope
  var statusBarController: StatusBarController?

even though its there. I have 0 swift experience, but I am reading that no import statement should be required to use custom classes.

What am I doing wrong that the app woun't build?
I tried removing pod files, opened the workspace in XCode, cleared all builds, always same error, no matter if built in CLI or within XCode. I assume I have to set some kind of PATH to find it, like PYTHONPATH during the build? But it sits right next to the AppDelegate.swift file...
Thank you for any suggestions!

have you tried "flutter doctor"

All looks good for MacOS...
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

The root cause was simple yet surprising.
I had created the swift file manually in VSCode. It therefore has not been listed in the macos/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and not added to the build.
I removed the file, created it within XCode and pasted the content. Viola, it builds...
